# Is it possible to share a directory for multiple user in laravel filemanger?

Tags: laravel

I have used laravel filemanager in some of my projects. I want to know is it possible to share a directory for say 4-5 users so every group of users can access one specific direcory?

Answer (score 0):

If two user have identical ID "or belongs to same group" then its possible to user share same directory

or you can Query::all so that all user can see other users uploaded files. But this will be below standard